# Python / IDLE CPU usage for no reason

Tags: python, cpu-usage, python-idle

Here is a strange problem I have with IDLE (version 2.6.5 with the same Python version) on windows.

I try to run the following three commands:

```
fid= open('file.txt', 'r')
lines=fid.readlines()
print lines
```

When the print lines command is executed, the pythonw.exe process is going CPU crazy, consuming 100% of CPU and the IDLE seems to not be responding. The file.txt is around 130 kb - I don't consider that file very large !

When the lines finally print (after some minutes), if I try to scroll up to see them, I once again experience the same very large CPU usage.

The memory usage of pythonw.exe is around 15-16 MB all the time.

Can anybody explain to me this behaviour - obviously this can't be a bug in IDLE since it would have been discovered ... Also, what can I do to supress that behavior ? I like using IDLE for script like tasks involving data transformations from files.

Comment: `130kb`, it's in the question.

Comment: Do you experience the same behavior with the std interpreter (python.exe instead of IDLE using pythonw.exe)?

Comment: @Xavier: Actually no, the command line interpreter python.exe works very nice, even with larger files (I opend a 426 kb txt file with no problem) ! Also, the memory usage of python.exe was 3 MB - when I opened and read the liens of the the 426 KB file it went to 3,5 MB \o/ So probably that's a problem with IDLE on Windows - can anybody confirm this please ?

Comment: This is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743715/python-idle-freezes/8172787

Answer (score 2):

Try reading it line by line:

```
fid = open('file.txt', 'r')

for line in fid:
  print line
```

From the documentation on [Input Output](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), there seem to be two ways to read files:

```
print f.read() # This reads the *whole* file. Might be bad to do this for large files.

for l in f:    # This reads it line by line
  print l      # and prints it. Might be better for big files.
```

Comment: Ok that could be a solution however I really prefer working with lists in python, using list comprehension instead of loops. For really large files maybe, but for nomal ones I'd use the command line python.exe as I mention in another comment...