# IDLE crashing with url read

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

I'm trying to create a lesson on string manipulation for my Year 8 Computing class (12-13 year olds). I want them to grab text from a website and thought that it might be cool to use War and Peace. However, IDLE keeps crashing when I try to read the URL. It works fine in the terminal on a Mac or in Command Line on a PC (takes 5-10 seconds to run), however my students don't have access to the Command Line for network-security reasons.

My code looks like this

```
import urllib2
site = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2600/pg2600.txt')
site.read()
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Does it crash with any error message?

Comment: Please tag this as homework. Also, you need more information, like operating system, version of Python and so on. I just did this in the Python IDLE and it dumped out the text just fine.

Comment: OSX 10.7.4 (2.2GHz i7, 4GB RAM), Python 2.7.3. Why do you want me to tag as homework? I'm a teacher, not a student.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [this page](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/) about using IDLE under OS X?  You will need to first install a newer Tcl/Tk package if you haven't already.

Comment: It does the same on Windows unfortunately.

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have to say teaching Python in Year 8 is cool, War and Peace is cool too :)

The guy who is not cool is IDLE (Or Tcl/Tk I should say), it suffers when handling large amount of text printing, War and Peace is too much for him.

Try limit the amount of text you print like this:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> site = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2600/pg2600.txt')
>>> site.read()[:1024]
```

Comment: Cheers. It looks like I'll have to find another IDE with an interactive shell. I've tried upto 'site.read(100000)' but increasing by a factor of 10 causes the crash. Really want the kids to have access to the entire text.

Comment: @mjscott If you have the option to deploy new programs, you may want to try http://dreampie.sourceforge.net/, it handles War and Peace well.

Comment: Thanks. Installing now on my Mac. Will let you know how I get on. I'm the net admin at school as well as a teacher so will get an msi built and deploy tomorrow if it works.

Comment: It works fine in CodeRunner, and I can get PyScripter on the network for the kids as this worked well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could just read the whole thing line by line, something like this:

```
import urllib2

site = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2600/pg2600.txt')
for line in site:
    # print it or do whatever
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll give that a go in IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE slows down when displaying long lines in the shell. Take a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743715/python-idle-freezes).

You need the [Squeezer](http://bugs.python.org/issue1529353) extension for IDLE. The [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net) project provides Squeezer as well as other useful extensions for IDLE.